# Tuesday Fast eating doubts

Tags: hanuman, food, fasting, vrata

I fast every Tuesday since 3 years. Firstly I used to eat jaggery with wheat chappati but someone told me that once a day I can eat salty food also. But I watched somewhere and someone told me that only jaggery along with wheat we should eat. Is it right or we can eat any food once on Tuesday?